Warning: 'Not found' when trying to publish content in a locale in strapi
Objective
I want to create content for different locales and fetch them in a next.js app to enable i18n

Issue
When publishing the draft version of a content type after populating it with data, it throws a warning, which reads 'not found'
http: POST /content-manager/single-types/api::test.test/actions/publish?locale=es (15 ms) 404

Troubleshoot

I've provided all the permissions for public and authenticated users
I've added locales in i18n from the global settings
I've enabled i18n for the content type from the builder page

Project details
{
  "name": "protean-x-strapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.21.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.21.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.21.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.21.1",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "2e6b5187-b712-4fe8-976c-849661638d60"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}


Closing
Why am I getting this error?
I do not understand, what am I missing?
I've tried deleting the folders (build, node_modules, .strapi, .tmp) and then rebuilding it again, but still no luck.
What am I missing?

Hello, what is your content structure for that single type?

Hi @JimLAURIE, the issue was resolved.
There was an error with strapi code, (i lost the github issue) the team released a new patch...it worked on either downgrading the strapi version or upgrading to the latest. I upgraded the code
